# Laravel Modules + VueJS, routes are being overwritten

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

Well, I have a problem with my routes, all requests related to the Modules folders don't work. I'm using [laravel-modules](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules) package.

In my `project-folder/routes/web.php` I must use a wildcard route because my front is in VueJs SPA:

```php
Route::get('/{any}', 'ApplicationController')->where('any', '.*');
```

Ok, I was using my API routes into the main `api.php` file, working fine, but when I put in `Modules/ModuleName/Routes/api.php` the route doesn't work.

If I remove the `Route::get('any')` from main `web.php` it works,
I believe the routes are having some kind of conflict.

```
+-----------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Method    | URI                          | Action                                                                         | Middleware   |
+-----------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| GET|HEAD  | api/opportunity/channel-sale | App\Modules\Opportunity\Http\Controllers\OpportunityController@channelSaleList | api,auth:api |
| GET|HEAD  | api/opportunity/flow-steps   | App\Modules\Opportunity\Http\Controllers\OpportunityController@flowStepList    | api,auth:api |
| GET|HEAD  | api/opportunity/kanban       | App\Modules\Opportunity\Http\Controllers\OpportunityController@kanbanList      | api,auth:api |
| GET|HEAD  | api/user                     | Closure                                                                        | api,auth:api |
| GET|HEAD  | {any}                        | App\Http\Controllers\ApplicationController                                     | web          |
+-----------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: What is `Modules/ModuleName/Routes/api.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here, either pass a regular expression to the `any` route to ignore API prefixed routes

```php
Route::get('/{any}', 'ApplicationController')->where('any', '^(?!api).*$');
```

Or set a fallback to the `ApplicationController`

```php
Route::fallback('ApplicationController');
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/routing#fallback-routes)

#### Fallback Routes

Using the `Route::fallback` method, you may define a route that will be executed when no other route matches the incoming request. Typically, unhandled requests will automatically render a "404" page via your application's exception handler. However, since you may define the `fallback` route within your `routes/web.php` file, all middleware in the `web` middleware group will apply to the route. You are free to add additional middleware to this route as needed:

```php
Route::fallback(function () {
    //
});
```

> The fallback route should always be the last route registered by your application.